# PullWithQuery not returning data from remote server

Tags: ios, iphone, azure

I am using Azure Mobile Service as my app backend. I am trying to sync data as mentioned in Azure demo "TodoItem". Every thing working fine but only data is not pulled from remote server.

I am using custom API (invokeAPI methods.)

Here is my code:

```
[self syncData: ^
{
    // Let the caller know that we finished
    if (completion != nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
    }
}];

-(void)syncData:(QSCompletionBlock)completion
{
    // push all changes in the sync context, then pull new data

    [self.client.syncContext pushWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
        [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];
        [self pullData:completion];
    }];
}

-(void)pullData:(QSCompletionBlock)completion
{


    // Pulls data from the remote server into the local table.
    // We're pulling all items and filtering in the view
    // query ID is used for incremental sync

    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"complete == NO"];
    MSQuery *query = [self.syncTable queryWithPredicate:predicate];

    [self.syncTable pullWithQuery:query queryId:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
        [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];

        // Let the caller know that we have finished
        if (completion != nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
        }
    }];
}
```

Here nothing saved to local data base from server.

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass queryId as nil.

Pass some string to it like below.

[self.syncTable pullWithQuery:query queryId:@"allitems" completion:^(NSError *error){
}